# Need to iterate through two arrays of items for comparison without parallelism

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

So for my java class I have to write a program that accepts toppings and adds 75 cents to total price for every topping. I haven't bothered for null testing yet because of this error. Essentially I will have:

```
list1 = Valid Toppings
list2 = User Toppings
```

User toppings can be entered in any order so it doesn't make any sense to match them as a parallel array. You can see the logic I have used in the code snippet below, but it is not legal. My terminal vomits everywhere when I try to compile. How would I go about implementing the logic below, or perhaps a better way of implementing my logic completely?

```
  for(x = 0; toppings.length < 3; x++)
    {
      if(toppings[x].equals(for(xx = 0; validToppings[0].length < 3; xx++) {validToppings[xx]})
        {setSize(size); price += .75;}
        else
        {System.out.println("Error in Pizza class: Attempt to set invalid pizza topping" + x + "(" + toppings[x] + ")")};
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you are trying to test whether one array of strings is in another array of strings, (as in, a 'subset' in Set Theory). Then why not use `ArrayList`, something like this: (sorry if my syntax is a little off it's been a while since I did java)

```
ArrayList<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();
toppings.add("Pepperoni");
toppings.add("Olives");

ArrayList<String> validToppings = new ArrayList<>();
validToppings.add("Pepperoni");
validToppings.add("Salami");
validToppings.add("Olives");
validToppings.add("Cheese");

boolean toppingsValid = validToppings.containsAll(toppings);
```

Comment: It's a homework assignment, so OP is likely stuck using primitive arrays.  Next, that syntax is pretty far off, although the point is pretty clear.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that it was for homework, my bad. OP, if you haven't learned to use (or told explicitly not to use) collections and set theory, disregard this answer. Also feel free to edit the syntax to be java like @Makoto, I did mention that its been a while since I've done Java

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are trying to use an if statement, which does a single boolean comparison, to a for statement, which can not be made into a boolean.

Do it like this instead:

```
for(int x = 0; topping.length < 3; x++){
         for(int xx = 0; vaildToppings[0].length < 3; xx++){
             if(toppings[x].equals(validToppings[xx]){
//do stuff
     }
}
```

Nested for loops are your friend.

topping.length < 3 as your conditions to close is also non nonsensical. Consider reexamining your logic, I don't know what you are actually trying to do, so I'm not going to make any assumptions.

Comment: There is also the problem that topping.length < 3 is not a valid endcase for a for loop. And that no counter types had been declared.

Comment: @Colleen didn't even catch that, nice. I'll update the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is breaking is because you have toppings.length < 3  and validToppings[0].length < 3 when you want, presumably,  x < 3 or x < toppings.length

Everything in your for loop should be based on your counter.

Comment: Loop counter doesn't have to be `i`, so there's nothing wrong there.  There isn't a declaration of type for `x` or `xx` though, so this answer isn't incorrect...

Comment: sorry, I assumed it was i (updated it so it's x), but you're not getting the point. Also, if this is java, you do need a declaration of a type for x.

Comment: I have declarations for x and xx.

Pizza.java:88: illegal start of expression
          if(toppings[x].equals(for(xx = 0; validToppings.length < 3; xx++) {validToppings[x]})

My guess is I cannot nest a for within an if like I have.

Comment: As in the other answer, you must declare your variable types like for(int i=0... not just for(i=0.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < toppings.length; x++)
{
    if (!validToppings.contains(toppings[x]))
    {
        //throw some error, or print a message, etc....
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't iterate over the other array.

Comment: it does what OP needs it to do, though (unless they're required to do a nested loop). Do you know what .contains() does?

Comment: .contains() does a nested loop internally, it functions just like a nested for loop, but looks nicer.

Comment: @Colleen: Nothing in the code suggests that he's implemented `List<E>` in his code, so I don't see how `contains()` would apply.

Comment: Keep in mind this seems to be homework, and methods like .contains() are generally not allowed. I remember in high school (which this is undoubtedly from) that we were only allowed primitive arrays. No arraylists or anything! So annoying.

Comment: Just because contains isn't implemented right now isn't a reason to say this answer is wrong, though. And yes, while lots of homework like this does have those kinds of restrictions, they weren't defined in the problem statement. This is a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

A nested for-loop is the right approach here.  Don't forget to declare the type of your loop counter in the loop itself (or elsewhere, if you want to use C style), or you'll get compiler errors all day.

```
for(int x = 0; x < toppings.length; x++) {
    for(int xx = 0; xx < validToppings[0].length; xx++) {
        if(toppings[x].equals(validToppings[xx]) {
            // Perform operations here.
    }
}
```

As a side note:  `toppings.length < 3` may or may not be true throughout the loop; it could never be true, thus causing the loop not to execute, or it could be true, causing an infinite loop, regardless of `x` or `xx`.  Be careful for cases like that.

Comment: You again did not address the fact that toppings.length < 3 is an invalid end case for the for loop.